# Intersection points between 2 lines and third one with a specific length and angle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We have 2 line segments AB and AC. We cross this two lines by HM segment in a way that HM have a specific length. HM is parallel so either oX or oY. How to find points H and M if they present?

[image: Image description]

Comment: When you say "oX or oY", do you mean the $x$ and $y$ axes?

Comment: @Arthur yes, you are right!

Comment: What is the relation of oX, oY and (0,0) to the drawing?

Comment: How AB (ab), AC (ac) are defined?